# why can argv use increment operator

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, increment, argv

it's in K&R's book

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    while (--argc > 0)
        printf("%s%s", *++argv, (argc > 1) > " " : "");
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

in this book, it says that array can't use increment or decrement operator, in this program ,"argv" should be an array's name, why it can use increment operator?

Comment: `argv` is not an array, it's a pointer because in a function argument, array types are adjusted to pointer types.

Comment: Because array types are adjusted ....so it is an Array

Comment: @Michi no, it's not an array, read my comment.

Answer (score 6):

The second parameter of the main

```
char *argv[]
```

is adjusted to pointer to the first element of the array. That is it has type

```
char **argv;
```

You may increase pointers.

Thus as initially `argv` (adjusted to pointer) points to the first element of an array of pointers to strings then `++argv` points to the second element of the array and so on.

According to the C Standard ([6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes)](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#6.7.6.3p7))

> 7. A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of type’’ shall be adjusted
>      to ‘‘qualified pointer to type’’, where the type qualifiers (if any)
>      are those specified within the `[` and `]` of the array type
>      derivation.

Comment: This quote is incomplete, you should clarify that it only applies in function declarators.

Answer (score 2):

You are wrong. `argv` isn't an array. It is a pointer to a pointer to a `char`. Pointers can be incremented / decremented. And

```
main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

is the same as

```
main(int argc, char **argv)
```

Comment: i get it,but, is there any difference between char *[] and char **?

Comment: because array decays into pointer - `char *[]` and `char**` are essentially the same (pointer to pointer to char).

Comment: @Micheal In this case, no, there is no difference. `char*[]` is adjusted to `char**` as @Vlad pointed out in [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32034124/3049655)

Comment: @CoolGuy char *string[] is an array of strings (character pointers)  not pointer to pointer, or i understand the things wrong ?

Comment: @Michi , If you specify a valid size between `[` and `]`, then **yes**. But in case of function parameters, they are the same as `char**`.

Comment: @Michi It depends on where the object is declared. `[]` means "array" in all cases **except for function arguments,** where it means "pointer".

Comment: @artm **no, you are wrong,** this is **not** about array-to-pointer decay. That's about expressions of array types. This rule is array-to-pointer adjustment of **declarations** and is specifically valid for function parameters **only,** whereby array-to-pointer decay is performed in many more scenarios.

Comment: You do not try to increment/decrement the array..but the pointer inside the array. Or I'm wrong

Comment: @Michi What array are you taking about?